# Green color not so green on my mac?

Tags: macos, mac, color

First I've noticed it on my activity monitor:
[image]
As you can see *Free* ram color is set to bright green. And in the activity monitor itself shows color somewhat between green and yellow.
Now also as you can see in bottom left corner, the dock icon's color is ok.

But in the Terminal I get the same crappy color instead of green…
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

### EDIT

After rebooting the *Activity Monitor* it's colors went back to normal. Haven't tried to do it with terminal yet.

Comment: Did you ever try calibrating your display? You could do that manually, but even better would be with a calibration device.

Comment: @Gerry can you suggest any? I've never done that.

Comment: I personally bought the Datacolor Spyder3 Pro and am quite happy with it.

Comment: @Gerry After rebooting the _Activity Monitor_ it's colors are ok…

Comment: Filing this one under "not able to reproduce"!  Weird.

Comment: You could (have tried to) select a different color profile from the color picker, see [Is it possible to disable Terminal's automatic tweaking of colors in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487/is-it-possible-to-disable-terminals-automatic-tweaking-of-colors-in-lion).

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this behaviour if I use different screens with the same windows. Somehow Mac OS seems to save the colour profile with the monitor where the window has been initially opened. If I open the same window on a different screen e.g. green looks different than it should be.